# Curating and sharing a project's visual assets

Tags: tools, resources

I’ve got a question about public **visual asset** storage for the group.

I work at a small boutique-style consultancy that includes 9 back-end devs, 1 UX designer (me), and a business development person.

I work closely with our developers on our projects, by writing front-end code and collaborating with developers to design the UIs for the web apps we work on.

I often come out of design sprints with a wide range of requirements from clients that may include anything from high fidelity clickable prototypes to as quick and dirty as whiteboard sketches.

This means that for any given project I’ve got folders full of references that I later use when I’m coding the front-end of our web apps or that developers use as references when architecting the database and building the back-end.

A few months ago I had this idea to use Pinterest’s private boards to display visual assets. My reason for hopping on Pinterest was mostly a convenience decision since I was already using it to curate design inspirations… but I’ve since found our developers getting increasingly frustrated by Pinterest’s shotty UX and roadblocks from signing up for an account and getting access to the boards they’re invited to contribute to.

**TL;DR - What do you use to curate visual assets for projects that both your in-house team and external clients can have access to?**

Comment: More details: We have a 'war room' in the office that serves as our visual anchor for projects. Each project gets a whiteboard during the design sprint which is smattered with everything from the project [elevator pitch](http://gamestorming.com/games-for-design/elevator-pitch/) to [wireframe concepts](https://www.behance.net/wip/1145705) and [wireframes of UIs](https://www.behance.net/wip/1145809/2031695).

In short - we're looking for a solution that mimics the meta view of a project the way a 9 foot whiteboard would display those things IRL.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **[Pixelapse](https://www.pixelapse.com/)**. They have version control, shared workflow, public gallery, commenting, annotations and some other features that can be useful in a shared working environment.

**Github** also supports [PSD viewing and diffing.](https://github.com/blog/1845-psd-viewing-diffing)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

My guess you could use [**InVision**](http://invisionapp.com/). They have a really good sharing/commenting system. You could just set up a folder inside a project that's called "Initial Assets" — and then display all the follow-up work in other folders.

**Dropbox** has also been offering commenting for a while, but I personally haven't had a chance to explore it.